# How does the /dev/input folder get updated

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, udev, devices, input

I understand that `evdev` is used to get raw data from input devices such as keyboards and provide it to user space via files inside `/dev/input/` for example  `/dev/input/event0` .

Let's take a non-standard input device, for example a special touchscreen. How does or should this `/dev/input` directory get populated on bootup to contain the device file for the touchcreen device? Should this be created by the actual kernel device driver for the touchscreen?

I'm now confused about the role of `udev` here. My understanding is that `udev` manages the creation of the device files inside `/dev` ?

Comment: "Let's take a non-standard input device" Do you mean some input device for which hid-generic would not be of any help ? More precisely some touchscreen that would not be handled by hid-multitouch ? ( https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/hid/hid-multitouch.c )

Comment: @MC68020 Let's just take any any device for argument sake. I'm trying to see viisualize what happens on bootup. What role udev, evdev has, how the /dev/input file gets created etc.

Comment: me too. im baffled trying to understand how the bluetooth id and name get mapped into evdev because i have a device where these two have nothing in common